# What does "Menu block title" (accessibility_title) do on the Accessibility tab of the Page content element type in TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, typo3-9.x

### The Question

What does `Menu block title` (accessibility_title) do on the `Accessibility` tab of the `Pages` content element type in TYPO3 9.5?

### More Info

I looked at the HTML in the frontend after I fill out the `Menu Block Title` field and expected some `aria` attribute or something but can't see any changes in the frontend when this is filled out.

### Images

Here's the `General` and `Accessibility` tabs of the `Pages (Menu of selected pages)` content element...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not a typo3 person but the names in red in square brackets seem like internal names. They're not related to any ARIA attributes (looking at the bypass block section). Does the bypass block section work? I know that's unrelated to your question but it might help. Check the option on and specify the link text and see if a bypass block is generated (it won't have any ARIA attributes). There was a bug on that that was fixed a while ago, https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58290. For the `menu block title`, my guess is that an `aria-label` would be generated on a `<nav>`. Do you see a `<nav>`?